# UDP packets doesn't get fragmented when generated from namespace

Tags: networking

Below is the output of command **ip link**:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
9: veth1@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether e6:f9:cf:3c:41:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

When I use **iperf3** to send udp packets across the namespace of size **8KB** and the packets on wireshark. The packets doesn't get fragmented even when MTU is set as 1500 on both the virtual interfaces across the namespace.

What should I do to get fragmented packets from the namespace?
Below is the **tcpdump** output:

```
14:57:51.806895 IP Wimax-Cali-190-0-1-2.orbitel.net.co.58280 > 190.0.1.1.5201: UDP, length 4
14:57:51.807058 IP 190.0.1.1.5201 > Wimax-Cali-190-0-1-2.orbitel.net.co.58280: UDP, length 4
14:57:51.846706 IP Wimax-Cali-190-0-1-2.orbitel.net.co.58280 > 190.0.1.1.5201: UDP, length 8192
14:57:51.946975 IP Wimax-Cali-190-0-1-2.orbitel.net.co.58280 > 190.0.1.1.5201: UDP, length 8192
14:57:51.947027 IP Wimax-Cali-190-0-1-2.orbitel.net.co.58280 > 190.0.1.1.5201: UDP, length 8192
14:57:51.947048 IP Wimax-Cali-190-0-1-2.orbitel.net.co.58280 > 190.0.1.1.5201: UDP, length 8192
14:57:51.947068 IP Wimax-Cali-190-0-1-2.orbitel.net.co.58280 > 190.0.1.1.5201: UDP, length 8192
```